# How to repaint a XYPlot from JFreeChart? (JAVA)

Tags: java, user-interface, jfreechart

I'm doing a GUI that has a `XYPlot` (from the JFreeChart package) and when I click a button I'm trying to add some values. I add them correctly to the `XYSeries` that are inside the `XYPlot`, but the GUI doesn't change. It only changes when *y* maximize or minimize. Is there some kind of repaint to do this? I have been looking for it and I have found nothing.

Comment: Reformatted; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The `add()` methods of [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) send a `SeriesChangeEvent` to all registered listeners, some optionally; and the [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) content "is redrawn automatically whenever this notification is received."

You might compare what you're doing with [`org.jfree.chart.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html#line.69). Similarly, this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo) shows the effect of dynamically adding series to a data set.

Comment: I have executed this code and it doesn't seem to add data to the dataset after the view is shown. Am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: The first example does not; second example does.